# How to take off the preview icon from the ngx markdown editor?

Tags: angular, markdown

I want to use the ngx markdown editor with only the editor mode and without the preview. How can I get rid of the preview?
I changed the mode to editor but it didn't workout.
**(mode ="editor")**

**in the html**

```html
<md-editor name="Content" [(ngModel)]="competency.content" [height]="'425px'"
        required maxlength="500" ngPreserveWhitespaces [upload]="doUpload"
        [preRender]="preRenderFunc" [options]= "markDownEditorOptions" mode="editor">
      </md-editor>
```

**In the typescript file**

```
public markDownEditorOptions = {
    showPreviewPanel: false,     
    showBorder: true,          
    hideIcons: [],           
    usingFontAwesome5: true,   
    enablePreviewContentClick: false             
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default its mode is editor only. Kindly remove that mode config and try once.
If possible share the stackblitz for the same.